# SEND_SMS permission for a SMS Gateway application

Tags: android, android-permissions, sms-gateway

I'm trying to publish a SMS Gateway Android application to the PlayStore.

The application basically receives messages via socket.io through a background service and sends them via SMS (the message and recipient phone number are within the received messages).

From my understanding recently google has completely restricted the use for SEND_SMS permission outside apps that are not default SMS handlers - which my app is not.

Not sure if registering as a default SMS handler is the right solution since the application doesn't use the resto of the typical permissions for a SMS handler app (and can't do those functions, like read SMS).

Could there be a way to actually get my application approved or it's just a waste of time to argue with them?

EDIT:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVFvM.png) is the rejection reason

Comment: You can write the app and get it to work.  Just request the permission and use SMSManager.sendTextMessage.  Whether it will be allowed by the Play store based on Google's policies is another issue (probably not), but one that isn't on topic on this site.

Comment: What is the rejection reason on the Playstore?